# If all eigenvalues of $A$ are in unit disc then $A^n\to 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to prove that if $|\lambda|<1$ for every eigenvalue of the complex square matrix $A$ then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} A^n=0$$

I know that $\lim_{n\to \infty} A^n v=0$ for every eigenvector $v$ but can't proceed in the case $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A=\begin{bmatrix} 
\lambda & 1\\ 
 0&\lambda
\end{bmatrix}$, you can find that $A^n=\begin{bmatrix} 
\lambda^n & n\lambda^{n-1}\\ 
 0&\lambda^n
\end{bmatrix}$.

We will get $\lim_{n\to \infty} A^n=0$ since $\lim_{n\to \infty} n\lambda^{n-1}=0$.

For general case, any matrix $A$ can be transformed to Jordan Canonical form using similarity transformation, i.e. $A=T^{-1}JT$, where $J$ is Jordan Canonical form and $T$ is invertible matrix. Then $\lim_{n\to \infty} J^n=0$ implies $\lim_{n\to \infty} A^n=0$. Since $|\lambda|<1$ for every eigenvalue, you can use similar argument for each Jordan block.

$n'$th power of general $k\times k$ Jordan block is given by

$J_k(\lambda)^n = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1} & \binom{n}{2}\lambda^{n-2} & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{n}{k-1}\lambda^{n-k+1} \\
 & \lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1} & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{n}{k-2}\lambda^{n-k+2} \\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 &  & & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 &  & &  & \lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1}\\
 &  &  &  &  & \lambda^n
\end{bmatrix}$,

so one might attempt to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \binom{n}{k-1}\lambda^{n-k+1}=0$.